# How to Install/rollback to a specific version of Microsoft Edge on Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-edge

I am looking for a way to rollback Windows Microsoft Edge to a previous version but it seems impossible to do.

I understand they dont want people to do this for security reasons. But I have a valid reason we collect analytics for our app and log versions firmware etc and in our analytics software we can see that certain users on a specific version of Edge are having lots of issues.

So ideally we need to rollback to the version with the issue and try to recreate it.

We are seeing issues on 108.0.1462.46 but the current version is 108.0.1462.54

You can get the older version from these links.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/business/download?form=MA13FJ
https://microsoft-edge.en.uptodown.com/windows/versions

I have tried nearly every tutorial I can find online and cannot do this most are old and no longer relevant.

You can uninstall Edge using https://www.revouninstaller.com/products/revo-uninstaller-free/ and then try installing an older version but it always installs the latest no matter what I try.

I can install windows 10 without an internet connection and the in the EdgeUpdate folder rename the executable so it doesnt update and it will stay on its current version  98.0.1108.62 but this doesnt help.

Ive tried using gpedit.msc and changing the template files override target version etc.

Surely this is a valid reason to be able to rollback need to address bugs on versions of the browser lots of people are still using.

Has anyone successfully rollback to a previous version of Edge browser?

Answer (score 0):

The article
[How to rollback previous version of Microsoft Edge](https://pureinfotech.com/rollback-previous-version-microsoft-edge/)
contains detailed instructions on:

- Step 1: Install Microsoft Edge Group Policy templates
- Step 2: Disable Microsoft Edge updates:
  Using the Group Policy Editor, navigate to
  *Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Microsoft Edge Update > Applications > Microsoft Edge*, policy "Update policy override".
- Step 3: Download an older version of Microsoft Edge
- Step 4: Rollback to previous version of Microsoft Edge:
  Using the Group Policy Editor, navigate to
  *Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Microsoft Edge Update > Applications > Microsoft Edge* and set the "Rollback to target version" policy.

More details with screenshots can be found in the linked article.

Comment: Thanks, Have you had success getting these steps to work? I spent ages on this tutorial followed it fully and nothing worked!

Comment: Microsoft changes stuff all the time. I did verify that these group policies do exist, but did not enable them.